# how to use another project from android apps

Tags: android

I am very new to java and trying to develop an Android app called TACApp. I want to include a calandar (select dates and write them in the textbox) in my TACApp project for which I have separate calendar project in my workspace. I made a jar file out of the calendar project. I added the jar file in my TACApp library. I know it might be a basic question but can someone help me as to how I can get the contents of the jar file in my application? I don't want to use any class from the jar file i just need to show the Calender in my TACApp application. Is there any other way to do this. I have been researching for quite a while and thought this would be a good place to ask.. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the calendar project as a library project.
[Android Library Project creation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)
Reference this in the TACApp project. You can then launch your custom calendar activity with method startActivityForResult() using an Intent

Comment: Wow.. you just opened my eyes.. I have been searching everywhere for this for last 2 hours. i never had any clue on the same. I have added the library part and trying the intent part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way do you have any idea as to how I can show the calender project in the same screen? My calendar opens ofter selecting a data from a spinner. Or is there any better way to open the calendar. Thanks again